# Find $b$ so that $f(x,y) = y^3+3x^2y-15y-12bx$ has some critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve this excersice but I can't seem to get to anything but dead ends.

> Let $b\gt 0$ and $f(x,y) = y^3+3x^2y-15y-12bx$, find all possible values of $b$ so that $f$ has at least one critical point.

I started by deriving:

- $f_x(x,y) = 6xy-12b$
- $f_y(x,y) = 3y^2+3x^2-15$

So, if $(x,y)$ is a critical point:

- $xy = 2b$
- $x^2+y^2 = 5$

That would say that the possible values of $b$ are those that define an homographic function $y = \frac{1}{x}2b$ such that its graphic intersects with the border of the circle centered at the origin with radius equal to $\sqrt{5}$.

That is my intuition, but I can't seem to find a way of getting those values in numbers. I don't know if it would help, or if it is even correct, but I also attempted using Lagrange multipliers but that route didn't yield any valid result.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Find the minimum squared distance from the origin to the graph of $y=\frac{2b}x.$ If this minimum squared distance is greater than $5,$ it will not intersect the circle; otherwise, it will.

Comment: You mean like the function $d(x) = x^2 + \frac{4b^2}{x^2}$?

Comment: Yes! Can you determine when this achieves a minimum?

Comment: I seem to get that $d$ has a critical point when $x=\sqrt{2b}$ but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: That is nearly correct. It should actually be $x=\pm\sqrt{2b}.$ Regardless, plugging either of those values of $x$ in gives us $d(x)=2b+2b=4b.$ Hence, it will not intersect the circle when $4b>5,$ but will otherwise.

Comment: Got it. I wasn't plugging it back in $d$. Thank you very much, Cameron!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x^2 + y^2 \geq 2xy $  gives you the condition on $b$.

Comment: Wow, that was a good one! I get that $b \leq \frac{5}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2-2xy$, so your system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
(x+y)^2=5+4b\\
xy=2b
\end{cases}
$$
that forces $5+4b\ge0$ or $b\le-5/4$.

Once this condition is granted, you have two possibilities:
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=\sqrt{5+4b}\\
xy=2b
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
x+y=-\sqrt{5+4b}\\
xy=2b
\end{cases}
$$
The first corresponds to the roots of
$$
z^2-z\sqrt{5+4b}+2b=0
$$
which has discriminant $5-4b$, and this requires $b\le5/4$. The same for the second system. So, finally, you get
$$
-\frac{5}{4}\le b\le\frac{5}{4}
$$

Comment: Cool. I didn't see that "trick". As the instructions said that b is positive I can discard the negative values. Thanks a lot, egreg!

Comment: @John: Also, you can discard $0$.

Comment: @John Well, that restriction seems unnatural, because if you change $b$ into $-b$ and $x$ into $-x$ the function remains the same.

Comment: @CameronBuie The way with the minimum distance can be handy in other cases.

Comment: I will have both approaches in mind for the future. Thank you.